# Check null and emptry string in a cell while retrieving the excel data

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbexception

Error : Additional information: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[SKU N#] !='''.

```
 if (getFileExtension.ToLower() == ".xls")
                            {
                                conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + getFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;;IMEX=1\""; ;
                            }
                            else if (getFileExtension.ToLower() == ".xlsx")
                            {
                                conString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + getFileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;;IMEX=1\"";
                            }
                            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
                            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed) con.Open();
                            System.Data.DataTable ExcelSheets = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                            string SpreadSheetName = ExcelSheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                            switch (UpdateProductViewModel.ProductDataType)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    query = "SELECT * FROM [" + SpreadSheetName + "] WHERE [SKU N#] !='' AND [SKU N#] NOT LIKE '%P'";
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    query = "SELECT * FROM [" + SpreadSheetName + "] WHERE [SKU N#] !='' AND [SKU N#] LIKE '%P'";
                                    break;
                                case 3:
                                    query = "SELECT * FROM [" + SpreadSheetName + "] WHERE [SKU N#] !=''";
                                    break;
                            }
```

When I remove the **WHERE [SKU N#] !=''** this line from where it works fine. what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Try `WHERE NOT [SKU N#] = ''` instead.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Is '!=' NOT a valid operator?

Comment: @KeyurPATEL thanks for answer. Its working. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that **your column has `NULL` values** and **not just blank strings**.

**No value can ever be equal to (or not equal to) NULL because NULL has no value.**

`WHERE NOT [SKU N#] = ''` can work but is not probably the best way to check for NULL values.

I would suggest using `WHERE [SKU N#] IS NOT NULL AND [SKU N#] != ''`